# Sanity dataset import fails with `dataset does not exist or is not readable`

Tags: sanity

Simple question, trying to import a dataset fails with

```
$ sanity dataset import --replace production.tar.gz development
✔ [100%] Fetching available datasets
? Select target dataset Create new dataset
? Name your dataset: development

Error: /Users/...s/development does not exist or is not readable
```

This dataset did not exist, so created on the fly, I can see it on the management console and when you list the dataset using cli. Any ideas as to why this error occurs?

(Sanity cli version 3.8.3), same error happens on older 3.X.X cli as well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. If you are using the Visual Studio Code terminal, put your `tar.gz` inside your project directory. It seems like Visual Studio Code cannot read a file outside the project directory.

I used this command to import:

```
sanity dataset import production.tar.gz development --replace --allow-assets-in-different-dataset
```